# SSL between 2 Tomcat Servers

Tags: tomcat, cas, liferay

I'm trying to make 2 tomcat servers communicate by SSL (one with a CAS webapp, the other one with Liferay) both are on my computer.
The problem is that when Liferay tries to validate the ticket granted by CAS, it does not uses the SSL Connector I defined (I realised this when I looked at SSL trafic on localhost with wireshark), and so on, it does not uses the truststore defined in this connector.
That make an "unable to find valid certification path to requested target" error, and I have no idea about how to solve this...
The liferay connector:

```
<Connector port="9443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keyAlias="tomcat" 
           keystoreFile="D:\certs\keystore" keystorePass="passwd" 
           truststoreFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\jre\lib\security\cacerts" truststorePass="passwd"/>
```

The CAS one:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" SSLEnabled="true"
       maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keyAlias="tomcat" 
           keystoreFile="D:\certs\keystore" keystorePass="passwd" 
           truststoreFile="D:\certs\truststore" truststorePass="passwd"/>
```